# Using SUM(Total). SQL statement works fine in PHP+MySQL

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2015

I'm attempting to re-use some mySQL in my Visual Studio 2015 C# project. I'm attempting to retrieve an output from the database which sums up the sales and total sale volume for each salesman. When using the mySQL statement that works great in my PHP project, I'm given the error:

`The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.`

AGENT structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AGENT] (
    [AgentID]   INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AgentName] TEXT NOT NULL,
    [OfficeKey] INT  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AgentID] ASC)
);
```

OFFICE structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OFFICE] (
    [OfficeID]       INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [OfficeLocation] NCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OfficeID] ASC)
);
```

SALE structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SALE] (
    [SaleID]         INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SaleDate]       DATE            NOT NULL,
    [AgentKey]       INT             NOT NULL,
    [Amount]         MONEY           NOT NULL,
    [DestinationKey] INT             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SaleID] ASC)
);
```

Here is my source:

```
namespace Desktop_Campus_Travel
{
    public partial class Agent_Bookings : Form
    {
        public Agent_Bookings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Agent_Bookings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<AgentBooking> agentList = new List<AgentBooking>();
            SqlConnection conn = Database.GetConnection();

            string selStmt = @"
SELECT AGENT.AgentName, 
       OFFICE.OfficeLocation,
       COUNT(AGENT.AgentID) AS Sales,
       SUM(SALE.Amount) AS Total 
FROM   AGENT 
       JOIN OFFICE 
         ON AGENT.OfficeKey = OFFICE.OfficeID 
       JOIN SALE 
         ON SALE.AgentKey = AGENT.AgentID 
GROUP  BY AGENT.AgentName";

            SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand(selStmt, conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = selCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    AgentBooking agent = new AgentBooking();
                    agent.AgentName = reader["AgentName"].ToString();
                    agent.OfficeLocation = reader["OfficeLocation"].ToString();
                    agent.Sales = reader["Sales"].ToString();
                    agent.Total = reader["Total"].ToString();

                    agentList.Add(agent);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex) { throw ex; }
            finally { conn.Close(); }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amount should be `money` rather than `NCHAR`. SUMing on a string doesn't make sense. MySQL is happy to do whatever it can to produce a result, rather than providing an error. SQL Server does not.

Comment: I tried changing the column type to `money` but I'm left with the same error message.

Comment: Give us the AGENT and OFFICE table definitions as well...

Comment: Added the other tables.

Comment: You try to group by `AGENT.AgentName` and the type is `Text`. Try changing it to `nvarchar(100)`. Sql Server is not happy to group by `Text` data type.

Comment: One more, you group by `AGENT.AgentName` and then try to select `OFFICE.OfficeLocation`. That will also not work in Sql Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Step 1

Change your Agent Table to

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AGENT] (
    [AgentID]   INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AgentName] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [OfficeKey] INT  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AgentID] ASC)
);
```

SQL Server is not happy to `GROUP BY` `TEXT` data type.

### Step 2

Change your query to

```
SELECT
    AGENT.AgentName, 
    OFFICE.OfficeLocation,
    SALE2.Sales,
    SALE2.Total
FROM 
    AGENT 
    JOIN OFFICE ON AGENT.OfficeKey = OFFICE.OfficeID 
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            SALE.AgentKey,
            COUNT(SALE.SaleID) AS Sales,
            SUM(SALE.Amount) AS Total 
        FROM   SALE 
        GROUP  BY SALE.AgentKey
    ) SALE2 ON SALE2.AgentKey = AGENT.AgentID
```

SQL Server is also not happy to select column that is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause when `GROUP BY` is used.

You can do only Step 2 without doing Step 1 and it will work, but `Text` datatype is deprecated ([MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)) so you **shouldn't** use it.

Comment: This fixed the issues I was having, thanks for explaining the logic. =)